# How to flip a geom_area to be under the line when using scale_y_reverse()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I had to flip the axis of my line, but still need the `geom_area` to be under the curve. However I cannot figure out how to do so.

This is the line of code I tried

```
ggplot(PalmBeachWell, aes(x=Date, y=Depth.to.Water.Below.Land.Surface.in.ft.)) + 
  geom_area(position= "identity", fill='lightblue') + 
  theme_classic() + 
  geom_line(color="blue") + 
  scale_y_reverse()
```

and here is what i got
[image]

Answer (score 4):

One option would be to use a `geom_ribbon` to fill the area above the curve which after applying `scale_y_reverse` will result in a fill under the curve.

Using some fake example data based on the `ggplot2::economics` dataset:

```r
library(ggplot2)

PalmBeachWell <- economics[c("date", "psavert")]
names(PalmBeachWell) <- c("Date", "Depth.to.Water.Below.Land.Surface.in.ft.")

ggplot(PalmBeachWell, aes(x = Date, y = Depth.to.Water.Below.Land.Surface.in.ft.)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = Depth.to.Water.Below.Land.Surface.in.ft., ymax = Inf),
    fill = "lightblue"
  ) +
  geom_line(color = "blue") +
  scale_y_reverse() +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]